# Support of $f \in k[x,y]/(xy,y^2)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Let $A = k[x,y]/(xy,y^2)$, where $k$ is a field, and take $f \in A$. I am working on an exercise that says prove that the support of $f$ (as a global section of the structure sheaf on Spec $A$) is either empty, the origin, or the entire space. I seem to be getting answers that is different from this, and I would appreciate if someone could show me how to do it. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Show that $A_x \simeq k[x]_x$ (we're throwing out the nonreduced point $(x,y)$). This is a domain, so the support of a section there is all or nothing.

Comment: Could you possibly explain me why the support of a section is all or nothing when it is a domain by any chance? Thanks!

Comment: Also, could you possibly be able to explain what is wrong here: $P =  (x+1,y)$ and  $Q = (x+2,y)$ are prime ideals of $A$. If I take a function $f = x+1 + I \in A$, then $f$ id $0$ at P, but not $0$ at Q... So it's neither empty, origin, or the whole space...

Comment: @user201886 This is a common mistake when talking about supports: $f$ has value $0$ in $P$ (by this I mean it's image in the residue field is zero) but its germ there is not zero.

Comment: The fact about domains is just because the maps $A \to A_{\mathfrak p}$ in that case are all injective.

Comment: I see. Thank you. I am still a bit confused about the first part, so I will make it into another question.

Comment: I think there is something I am missing (or not understanding correctly) because I am getting that it is not zero in the residue field at $Q$ either...

Comment: In the residue field at $Q$ it should have value $-1$.

Comment: @Hoot So the support is when the germ is not $0$? And that the germ of $x+1 + I$ is not $0$ at $P$ or at $Q$?

Comment: @user211392 A section is *supported* at a point $P$ if its image in $\mathcal O_{X, P}$ is nonzero. It *vanishes* at $P$ if its image in the residue field $k(P) = \mathcal O_{X, P}/\mathfrak m$. These are very different. The first is saying that small neighborhoods of $P$ don't "see" any nontrivial behavior out of the function whereas the second just means that it's zero at the point but may do something interesting nearby. Think of how a smooth function can vanish at a point but still have an interesting germ or Taylor expansion there.